# Sending a message to Discord with Python using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a bot that monitors stuff online, and I have the code done and it runs in Terminal. I want to print my results within a channel in Discord using discord.py *without* having to require a command/input from a Discord user. I just want my program to send a message to my server in Discord when it picks up a product online. How can I do this?

Comment: Look into using [webhooks](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks). And the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook) in case you're interested in incorporating it into a bot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the channel from id then send it using `send`.

Code (assuming your client is `client`):

```py
channel = client.get_channel(123456789) # get channel from id
await channel.send('message here') # send message
```

Comment: When I put that, it says await outside of async function?

Comment: @cxiw What is your code for checking product stuff?

Comment: Here's my else statement for no restock found: else:
            print("NO RESTOCK FOUND...STILL MONITORING")

            client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

            channel = client.get_channel(123456789)
            await channel.send('NO RESTOCK FOUND')

Comment: You can use [discord.ext.tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop) and put your check logic there.